# Duplicate entity names are not allowed - Mikro Orm

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I created a migration for an entity in Mikro Orm. After that, i modified the entity and ran the migrations again. Now nestjs keeps giving me this error.

This was my entity.

```
@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity<Task, 'id'> {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Property()
  description: string;
}
```

I created initial migration with `npx mikro-orm migration:create --initial`. After that i modified my entity to this:

```
@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity<Task, 'id'> {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Property()
  description: string;

  @Enum(() => TaskStatus)
  status: TaskStatus = TaskStatus.OPEN;
}

export enum TaskStatus {
  OPEN = 'OPEN',
  IN_PROGRESS = 'IN_PROGRESS',
  DONE = 'DONE',
}
```

After that, I ran two commands `npx mikro-orm migration:create` & `npx mikro-orm migration:up`.
Now NestJs keeps giving me this error.

```
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [InstanceLoader] MikroOrmModule dependencies initialized +43ms 
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 13528   - 02/06/2021, 6:59:14 pm   [ExceptionHandler] Duplicate entity names are not allowed: Task +409ms      
MetadataError: Duplicate entity names are not allowed: Task
    at Function.duplicateEntityDiscovered (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\errors.js:151:16)    at MetadataValidator.validateDiscovered (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataValidator.js:40:42)
    at MetadataDiscovery.findEntities (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:81:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async MetadataDiscovery.discover (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:34:9)
    at async Function.init (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\MikroORM.js:42:24)
    at async Injector.instantiateClass (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:290:37)
    at async callback (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:42:30)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:114:24)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (C:\dev\nodejs\nestjs\sandbox\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:46:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After investigation, the code can be run perfectly. There maybe some problems on the `node_modules` where some incomplete/incompatible packages exist.

The solution is to remove `node_modules` and reinstall again.

---

The steps you do is the following:

1. create a Task class
2. create migration file
3. modify the Task class
4. create migration file again
5. do the migration

If you modify the Task class without running migration command before, you will end up having 2 migration files with create task table command because mikro does not have any references of task table before any migration happened.

You can check the SQL in both migration files, it should be `create table task xxx`.

**Therefore, there is a way to solve it:**

- delete the 2nd migration file first
- run `npx mikro-orm migration:up` to create task table on DB without enum
- run `npx mikro-orm migration:create`.

  > Right now, mikro has references of the task table and know that you want to alter table so the SQL in migration will be `alter table task` instead of `create table`
- run `npx mikro-orm migration:up` to alter task table on DB with enum

Comment: Migration is not the problem. Before the final migration, i applied the previous migrations and even inserted data into the database. https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1897

Comment: But can you confirm the migration file is using `alter table` SQL instead of `create table`?

Comment: I have checked the database and it's using the alter table command. The table in the database has the taskStatus column and even contains the previous data. I have even ran the npx mikro-orm migration:pending command to check if any migration is pending but it says that no migration are pending,

Comment: So do you mean the changes can be applied successfully but still showing `Duplicate entity names are not allowed: Task` error?

Comment: Yes changes are applied properly. But for some reason the entity is being discovered multiple times.

Comment: Cannot simulate your case. Have your tried to delete the sqllite file and run the migration again?

Comment: If there is still error after deleting sqllite db and running the migration. Is it possible for you to push the code to Github for us to study?

Comment: tested. no error on my side, your program can be run perfectly. I changed different versions of node and tested yarn & node. I think you can try to 1) remove node_modules -> reinstall -> try again,  2) try `yarn` instead of `node`, maybe node cached some dependencies.

Comment: Hey thanks for checking out my code. I deleted my `node_modules` and `dist` folder. Then it started giving me error that it couldn't find the `mikro-orm.config.js`. So, I updated it's new path to `./dist/src/mikro-orm.config.js` and the code started working now. Thanks again for helping me out. You should edit your answer so that i can mark it as answered.

Comment: i had the same error before where it cannot find the config.js. I used `yarn` instead of `npm`, then the problem is solved. I think npm caching mechanism somehow has a bit of problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue and I knew I didn't have a duplicate model name. The problem occurred after I had moved a model to a different directory.

The resolution was to clear the `dist` build folder and the `temp` metadata folders.

Comment: Same reason for occurrence here - I moved an entities directory and this was the error. Instead of manually deleting the folders I ran "nest build" again and it worked correctly.